# Posting a Tweet using Twitter4J via Android app

Tags: java, android, twitter4j

I am trying to post a tweet via my android app. Reading tutorials on the internet, I've written the code mentioned below.

However, I get the following exception each time, when calling twitter.updateStatus():

TwitterException{exceptionCode=[, statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}

Following things have been tried:
a. Reading the latest posts on this and other sites to understand a code defect.
b. Read about the error and suggested solutions.
b. Rebuilding workspace.

Any inputs will be REALLY helpful ! Thanks in advance.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.exampletweetdeep"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.exampletweetdeep.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.exampletweetdeep;

import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String consumerKey = "<<>>";
    String consumerSecret = "<<>>";
    String accessToken = "<<>>";
    String accessSecret = "<<>>";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("Twitter activity", "First line");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i("Twitter activity", "Before building configuration");

        ConfigurationBuilder confB = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        confB.setDebugEnabled(true);
        confB.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
        confB.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
        confB.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
        confB.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessSecret);

        Log.i("Twitter activity", "After building configuration");

        TwitterFactory tF = new TwitterFactory(confB.build());
        Twitter twitter = tF.getInstance();

        try {
            Status status = twitter.updateStatus("Testing from android");

            Log.i("Twitter activity", "Done updating status");
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your `twitter4j` library to `twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar`. I was facing the same problem and solved it by upgrading the library.